# Can i Use a 19v Charger for 10.5v Netbook

Tags: battery-charging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

I just lost my netbook charger and am now using my laptop universal charger for it.

The charger is supplies 19v and the battery has 10.5v written on it.

Will this just mean it will charge faster or can the battery  be damaged

Comment: Depends on Your Notebook charging Circuit. Most of the times, it will work but heat up your notebook.

Comment: @Swanand - Exceeding nameplate specs by 100% usually results in failure, not overheating. I think it's a very bad idea.

Comment: I closed this question as off topic, because you'll find the information in the linked one. But power supplies for consumer devices are not on topic here.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate question. He is asking about a special case - it's easy to read the questiin as "does charger of V1 volts work in place of charger of V2 Volts?". That is not what is being asked.

Comment: @Felix - What you have will  work well **IN SOME CASES** and you need to ask a  manufacturers agent or ask specifically in a forum of people who know. I have a netbook with a 19V charger. It can use 3S1P 3 cell batteries rated at a nominal 10.8 Volt or 4S2P, 8 cell batteries rated at a nominal 14.4 Volt. Presumably the internal power supply makes suitable decisions. This is not exactly what you are describing. A friend has a laptop with a 19V adapter. He assures me that he can use 12V battery feed directly to operate the laptop. Presumably the internal power supply is made to handle this.

Comment: The second case also is not what you describe. BUT these examples indicate that SOME laptop makers are implementing power suipply arrangements that can handle a range of adaptor and battery voltages. Yours may or may not **!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!** While it is clearly technically possible to do both the above it is by no means certain that manufacturers will do such things, so it is good to know that they are in fact doing so.

Comment: Thank you everyone and @clabacchio for not closing it until got a useful answer. I tested the netbook without the battery and it worked fine so there is definitely an internal power management circuit. It charged up quite quickly and still mantains its usual 9 hour battery life.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon it is not a duplicate question, indeed. But the other one can help Felix in understanding the problem, and his question would be off-topic anyways.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a good "universal" charger, it will have voltage selection slide switch somewhere to choose the value closest to your needs and not just plug adapters.

Although never connected directly to your internal batteries, DC-DC convertors onboard charge the battery cells for optimal efficiency based on a required input range, and then others for providing the on-board DC requirements.

Also buck regulators often have a wide range of input voltages but exceeding these unknown limits in your case might exceed the breakdown voltage of input capacitors and regulators, which may cause premature failure.  Using double the voltage is pushing it. Don't guess find out from the Mfg or get a proper range.

Look for a voltage selector switch or a universal with range options to suit your environment.